# Hyperinflation effects on mortgages

Tags: mortgage, inflation, europe, switzerland, hyperinflation

Is it conceivable that some kind of monetary reform would be carried out in western countries (or Europe, or Switzerland if that matters), in which assets and debts (mortgages) would be converted differently? Of course only in extreme conditions where inflation is very high.

Or other measures that could lead to the fact that property owners are not favored.

On the other hand, a (hyper-) inflation would devalue the debts and the house would remain stable in inflation-adjusted terms. This would in a way be unfair for people without home ownership, but on the other hand no one would argue for compensating the mortgage debt in case of deflation.

Comment: This feels a lot like an economics question, which would be off topic for the site. Can you tie this in to personal finance a bit more strongly?

Comment: what do you mean by "converted" The government cannot arbitrarily change the terms of your mortgage (at least not in the US or Europe to my knowledge)

Comment: Inflation is _good_ for fixed-rate debt holders. They can pay off the debt will less valuable units of currency. So it would be _good_ for property holders with mortgages.

Comment: Within the limits of the constitution of your country, governments can pass any laws they like to do anything they like.  So discussing what laws a government might pass if hyperinflation was to happen is just wild speculation.

Comment: @DStanley Quite recently, Hungarian government forcibly changed the currency of mortgages (ignoring conditions of the agreements). Yes, it has been controversial, but it has been carried through.

Comment: There is a lot that is "conceivable", especially in a situation which is as wildly hypothetical as a hyperinflation in Europe. Generally, inflation benefits the debtors, but in an extreme situation any kinds of extreme measures become plausible. I am voting to close this question as "primarily opinion-based", because it can only be answered with wild speculation about future events.

Comment: Obviously it's conceivable, since you've conceived of it :-)  But it would IMHO require something like a communist takeover, like 1917 Russia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hyperinflation is almost always disastrous for the country that experiences it.** Any country that expects it devotes any available effort to avoiding it, rather than mitigating its effects.

High inflation affects different people more or less. Property owners are not the only group disproportionately affected:

- Anyone owning tangible assets comes off well. This includes precious metals, commodities, real estate, and in some cases shares.
- Anyone invested in foreign assets, including foreign currency, comes off well.
- Anyone on a fixed income, including pensions, comes off very badly.
- Anyone who has purchased an annuity comes off badly.
- Anyone who has made loans in the expectation of profit comes off badly

Because of this it's virtually impossible to make something that compensates those badly affected (although some effort is usually made to adjust government pensions that become worthless as a result of inflation). During times of hyperinflation the government is usually in a financial crisis, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it conceivable ?

Sure. Almost everything is conceivable.

It's not likely in the current environment but both economic and political conditions can change drastically and pretty much everything can happen: laws can be changed, constitutions can be changed, revolutions can overthrow governments, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Real world example: in [Weimar Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic), once the situation stabilized with the introduction of the Rentenmark (at the rate of 10¹² of the old Marks), older mortgages were reinstated at [25% of their face value](https://positivemoney.org/2015/12/hyperinflation-how-the-wrong-lessons-were-learned-from-weimar-and-zimbabwe-a-history-of-pqe-part-2-of-8/).

Comment: 25% of their original value or 25% of their face value in Retenmark?

Comment: @DJClayworth since the Rentenmark value was equivalent to the pre-inflation Mark, there is no difference...

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of balancing going on in an economy.

Inflation, generally, is good for debtor (who can continue to earn an income) because they'll be advantaged by using future, less valuable dollars, to pay for capital they were able to use when it was more valuable.

In extreme inflationary situations, huge parts of the economy begin to malfunction.  Real GDP tends to decline, with less production comes less employment, less employment means less funded buyers to maintain the value of an asset like a house.  To some extent there's a chicken/egg issue with these things, it could be that inflation breeds less consumption which leads to less production demand which leads to less employment.  Whatever your philosophy on the topic the net result is less employment and corresponding less appetite for risk from lenders.

So yes, you'd be servicing your debt with less valuable currency but the value of your home may decline as the health of the economy deteriorates.

Generally speaking, what you want is smooth curves.  The interest rate doesn't matter much, dramatic movements in interest rates matter a lot.  And, generally speaking, it's better to have more of the population participating in GDP production because that means more people to support the value of your assets.